# Can We Have Multiple Spring Configuration Files in One Project?

Tags: java, spring

Can We Have Multiple Spring Configuration Files in One Project? If yes, can someone provide a working example to support this concept?

Comment: `tried few ways but it did not work` What did you try and how did you understand that it did not work?

Comment: There is far too little information to be able to answer this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in large projects, having multiple Spring configurations increase maintainability and modularity.

You can load multiple files like this:-

```
@Configuration
@Import({MainConfig.class, SchedulerConfig.class})
public class AppConfig {
```

You can also upload one XML file that will contain all configs.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-all.xml");
```

inside the XML file:-

```
<import resource="main.xml"/>
<import resource="scheduler.xml"/>
```

Comment: did you read the question? "Spring Configuration Files" != "Spring Configurations". And who still uses xml with Spring?